# cannot include concat in puppet

Tags: vagrant, puppet, concatenation

I have a problem in configuring puppet,
Here is my code to setup my environment:

```
node 'web' {     
  include concat, staging, java8, tomcat
}
```

and I downloaded and unzipped the file from https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/concat in `puppet/modules/concat`

but I get the following error

```
Could not find class concat for web.station on node web.station
```

My vagrant configuration file is:

```
config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
      puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
      puppet.module_path    = "puppet/modules"
      puppet.manifest_file  = "site.pp"
      puppet.options        = "--verbose --debug --parser future"    
 end
```

Comment: I would leave the default name puppetlabs-concat, and then `include puppetlabs-concat` and the folder name puppetlabs-concat and not concat

Comment: Dir names should _not_ have the author prefix, `concat` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The `concat` module doesn't contain any classes, there is no need to `include` anything to use it.

Your manifest should use the `concat` *resource* which will work automatically without any further configuration, e.g.

```
concat { '/tmp/file':
  ensure => present,
}

concat::fragment { 'tmpfile':
  target  => '/tmp/file',
  content => 'test contents',
  order   => '01'
}
```

(sample from the [puppetlabs-concat README](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/concat#overview))